# Is it DLL-Safe to return iterators?

Tags: c++, dll, vector

I'm referring to if the class comes from a DLL with its own heap, and it has a private vector, is it safe to have public functions which return iterators to that vector?

Thanks

Comment: Don't accept that answer. I'm fairly certain it's completely wrong, in answer and in comments, but I want to wait for his responses before I make my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not. The fact that it has its own heap is what will prevent it from working correctly.

Comment: I really don't see how it is not safe though, virtual memory model states that we all point to the same stuff, it would just be unsafe if you did: delete(*it); ... could you explain why it is not safe?

Comment: Because the CRT does a lot of heap checking to ensure that the exact situation you're trying to accomplish cannot be done (not to mention that it can't be done safely due to the fact that you'd have to absolutely ensure that every app accessing your DLL is compiled with the exact same version in the exact same mode with the exact same compiler defines of the CRT).

Comment: Nope. You can't return iterators at all.

Comment: Actually, there's one more thing you should know: you can't return any class objects from the CRT at all for the same reasons you can't return iterators.

Comment: Does this also apply to Linux development?

Comment: It applies to any C++ code that uses classes. If you can control all the source code from start to finish and can recompile it any time you make changes to the interface, then you can pull it off. Otherwise, don't even try.

Comment: @Jeff: The latter claims aren't true, you can return objects just fine. And I'm pretty sure the debug checking is sophisticated enough to handle differing heaps correctly, though I'm not as confident about that.

Comment: You can return objects, yes, because they are simply pointers. However, you can't safely interact with them across heap boundaries  because of how windows paging works and on a binary level because of how various compilers generate object layouts in memory. The short version is that you just don't do it.

Comment: @Jeff: Uh, what? You know we're talking about C++, right? How are objects "simply pointers"?

Comment: Either you're copying the whole object onto the stack, in which case you're invalidating the iterator by copying it, or you're passing a pointer to it, which doesn't work because you're trying to access memory in the wrong heap, which the CRT doesn't like. Take your pick.

Comment: Iterators aren't invalidated by copying... And you can access things from the "wrong heap" easily, that kind of information is part of the pointers address and not relevant. *Deleting* from the wrong heap is, of course, the actual problem.

Comment: Hmm. Well, I'm positive it doesn't work in the MS CRT, in any case--I've run into that problem twice so far.

Comment: "It" being passing objects (either as pointers or via copying) around between heaps.

Comment: @Jeff: Then that's incorrect. I do it all the time. By the way, pointers are technically objects.

Comment: Pointers aren't necessarily objects. Consider a primitive value located in the heap. If I pass an address to said primitive, that's a pointer but not an object. Either way, however, passing around iterators is a bad idea because of CRT versions and compilers generating potentially different and incompatible object layouts in memory.

Comment: @Jeff: In C++ "objects are a region of storage". You've just chosen, when using a pointer, to return an object that's been filled with a value that we'll call a pointer. Maybe iterators is indeed a bad idea, I don't know, but your claims about other things are certainly false, like "objects being pointers".

Answer (score 2):

Yes. One caveat: when using DLLs, use the C++ runtime DLL, not static linking.

You use static linking in 2 cases: when developing a standalone EXE (where the runtime DLL would be the first and only DLL) and when developing a reusable DLL without a C++ interface (i.e. either a C interface or a COM interface). Neither of these cases apply here. You must have a C++ interface to return iterators.

With dynamic linking of the C++ runtime, there's only one runtime.